# How to click dynamically created element to toggle drawdown in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function which I am using in various places all over my website. It works fine for all `li` elements with a class `dropdown` except for one which contains a number of `span` elements which get updated dynamically through jQuery.

When the stopwatch is running, I can click on the anchor text itself ("Stopwatch") to toggle the dropdown, but when I click on one of the `span` elements, nothing happens.

How can this be fixed?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    var menu = $(this).siblings('ul');
    menu.toggle();
    if (menu.is(':visible')) {
      $(this).addClass('expanded');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown" id="stopwatch">
    <a class="collapsible">Stopwatch
      <span id="clock">
        <span id="hours">00</span>
        <span id="minutes">00</span>
        <span id="seconds">09</span>
        <span id="milliseconds">120</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I suspect ``on('click', 'a', function(event)...`` is the problem. Have you tried without the ``'a'`` parameter?

Comment: What about posting a short CSS for proof-of-issue? Also, are you sure you don't have any listeners assigned on your `span` elements (with some stopPropagation)?

Comment: I copied your snippet to an answer and added "Stuff" to an li in the hidden menu.  Your logic works fine on the site.

Comment: @kmoser: Yes, I've also tried `$('.dropdown > a').on('click', function(event)` but with the same outcome.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Yes, I am sure I don't have any listeners on `span` elements. I just double-checked.

Comment: `$('.dropdown a').on('click', function(event)`